# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'littlelemonApi'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

``your tPerforming system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in                                     _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",     line 64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-      packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 133, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 485, in check

all_issues = checks.run_checks(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 88, in run_checks

new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
return check_resolver(resolver)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver

return check_method()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 494, in check
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns

patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in **get**
res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module

return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 690, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 940, in exec_module
File "", line 241, in *call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\USER\LittleLemon\littlelemon\littlelemon\urls.py", line 23, in 
path('api/',include('littlelemonApi.urls')),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\LittleLemon-a5AiNdQg\Lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 38, in include
urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 126, in   import_module
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1126, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "", line 1204, in _gcd_import
File "", line 1176, in _find_and_load
File "", line 1140, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'littlelemonApi'

I have cross checked all typos and urls.py on the project level and app level. i expext to run my server as it is an API project. my app_name is littlelemonAPI not littlelemonApi`